# python - locale in dateutil / parser

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I set

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, ('de', 'UTF-8'))
```

the string to parse is:

```
Montag, 11. April 2016 19:35:57
```

I use:

```
note_date = parser.parse(result.group(2))
```

but get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1531, in 
>       globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
>     File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 938, in run
>       pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
>     File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
>       exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
>     File "/Users/adieball/Dropbox/Multiverse/Programming/python/repositories/kindle/kindle2en.py", line 250, in 
>       main(sys.argv[1:])
>     File "/Users/adieball/Dropbox/Multiverse/Programming/python/repositories/kindle/kindle2en.py", line 154, in main
>       note_date = parser.parse(result.group(2))
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 1164, in parse
>       return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 555, in parse
>       raise ValueError("Unknown string format")
>   ValueError: Unknown string format

a debug show that parser is not using the "correct" dateutil values (german), it's still using the english ones.

[image]

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here, but can't find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dateutil.parser` doesn't use `locale`. You'll need to subclass [`dateutil.parser.parserinfo`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parserinfo) and construct a German equivalent:.

```
from dateutil import parser

class GermanParserInfo(parser.parserinfo):
    WEEKDAYS = [("Mo.", "Montag"),
                ("Di.", "Dienstag"),
                ("Mi.", "Mittwoch"),
                ("Do.", "Donnerstag"),
                ("Fr.", "Freitag"),
                ("Sa.", "Samstag"),
                ("So.", "Sonntag")]

s = 'Montag, 11. April 2016 19:35:57'
note_date = parser.parse(s, parserinfo=GermanParserInfo())
```

You'd need to extend this to also work for other values, such as month names.

Comment: If I recall correctly, there are downstream libraries that do handle other locales, such as [`dateparser`](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Probably better to use one of those than to maintain your own library of locale edge cases.

Answer (score 3):

In another answer, I answered a simple [Locale aware parseinfo class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62581811/10335). This isn't a complete solution for all languages in the world, but solved all my localization problems.

Here it is:

```
import calendar
from dateutil import parser
    
class LocaleParserInfo(parser.parserinfo):
    WEEKDAYS = list(zip(calendar.day_abbr, calendar.day_name))
    MONTHS = list(zip(calendar.month_abbr, calendar.month_name))[1:]
```

And you can use:

```
In [1]: import locale;locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "pt_BR.utf8")
In [2]: from localeparserinfo import LocaleParserInfo                                   

In [3]: from dateutil.parser import parse                                                

In [4]: parse("Ter, 01 Out 2013 14:26:00 -0300", parserinfo=LocaleParserInfo())              
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 1, 14, 26, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -10800))
```

Test it and take a look the class variables in the original parseinfo, specially the HMS variable. Maybe'll need to declare other variables.

Comment: For locale `fr` define months without the abbreviation dot, e.g.`MONTHS=list(zip(map(lambda x: x.replace(".", ""), calendar.month_abbr), calendar.month_name))[1:]`.

Answer (score 0):

### Multiple languages - Allow english and german month names

The way to implement multiple languages at once. I know there are other possibilites with `calendar.day_abbr, calendar.day_name` but this was the most convinient one for me. Just combine all the month names and list them down all togehter. These then will get accepted by the `dateutil.parser`

```
from dateutil import parser as dateparser

class LocaleParserInfo(dateparser.parserinfo):
        MONTHS = [('Jan', 'Januar', 'January', 'Jänner'),
                  ('Feb', 'Februar', 'February'),
                  ('Mrz', 'März', 'March', 'Mar'),
                  ('Apr', 'April'),
                  ('Mai', 'May'),
                  ('Jun', 'Juni', 'June'),
                  ('Jul', 'Juli', 'July'),
                  ('Aug', 'August'),
                  ('Sep', 'September'),
                  ('Okt', 'Oktober', 'October', 'Oct'),
                  ('Nov', 'November'),
                  ('Dez', 'Dezember', 'Dec', 'December')]

parsed_date = dateparser.parse("31 Jänner 2022", dayfirst=True, parserinfo=LocaleParserInfo())
parsed_date = dateparser.parse("31.December 2022", dayfirst=True, parserinfo=LocaleParserInfo())
```